# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'x' in 'where clause'

Tags: magento2

The whole error message is

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'root_category_id' in 'where clause'", query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `amasty_menu_item_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (`root_category_id`) = '2') ORDER BY sort_order ASC
```

I tried many things to solve this...

I deleted all generated files and cache files:

```
grunt clean
rm -rf generated var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed pub/static/*
```

Then I executed `php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

but it does still throw the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by deleting the folder of the module and installing it again via composer:

```
rm -rf vendor/amasty
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```